# jQuery sequenced events on click

Tags: jquery, events

So i have an area on a website what it will do is when clicked load some html(1), then once html(1) is loaded and that is clicked it will load some more html(2), then once html(2) is loaded and clicked it will load html(3) and finally once that is clicked it will go to a URL.

How would this be achieved ?

Just a basic example would help me get started !

What i am trying to achieve:

```
<div id="container">

     <div id="advert">
         Click this advert to crack the screen
     </div>
     <div id="crack-1" style="display:none;z-index:1;position:absolute;"></div>
     <div id="crack-2" style="display:none;z-index:1;position:absolute;"></div>
     <div id="crack-3" style="display:none;z-index:1;position:absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

1. So when the user clicks #advert for the first time #crack-1 is displayed;
2. when the user clicks #advert or #crack-1 (as #crack-1 is visible) #crack-2 is displayed;
3. when the user click #advert, #crack-1 or #crack-2 then #crack-3 is displayed;
4. when the user clicks #advert,    #crack-1, #crack-2 or #crack-3 then it goes to a url.

Comment: CAUTION my solution (further down) is invalid and should be deleted. i'm very sorry about this, but i didn't read the question carefully. my solution will only work for three different content containers, as everything inside $.when will be loaded synchronously. my apologies!

Comment: Not a problem @schellmax thanks for adding this comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/pQaR3/

JS:

```
$('#advert').click(function() {
    var self = this;
    if (!$('#crack-1').hasClass('open')) {
        $('#crack-1').show().addClass('open').click(function() {
            $(self).trigger('click');
        });
    } else if (!$('#crack-2').hasClass('open')) {
        $('#crack-2').show().addClass('open').click(function() {
            $(self).trigger('click');
        });
    } else if (!$('#crack-3').hasClass('open')) {
        $('#crack-3').show().addClass('open').click(function() {
            $(self).trigger('click');
        });
    } else {
        //follow some link
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$("#container").children().click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(":hidden:first").show();
    if($(this).siblings(":hidden").length===0){
        //all are shown!   
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @Chris Barr but Neal's solution worked perfectly.